# WebApi controller returning empty data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and create an app. I'm trying to make a Get request to retrieve a list of Books. This is my controller:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    Book[] books = new Book[] 
    {
        new Book(1, "Alice In Wonderland"), 
        new Book(2, "Dune"), 
        new Book(3, "Lord of the Rings")
    };

    public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
    {
        return books;
    }
...
```

And this is my model:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
    }

    public Book(int id, string name)
    {
        id = this.id;
        name = this.name;
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Before I had the empty constructor it was throwing a serialization error. Now it returns empty data:

```xml
<ArrayOfBook xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1.Model">
    <Book>
        <id>0</id>
        <name i:nil="true"/>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <id>0</id>
        <name i:nil="true"/>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <id>0</id>
        <name i:nil="true"/>
    </Book>
</ArrayOfBook>
```

I tried putting a breakpoint in the controller at `return books` and the list is not what I hardcoded it to be. It's 3 empty book objects.

I tried adding [Serializable] to the Book class and removed the empty constructor but it still just returns a set of empty books. Any ideas what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong assignment statements in the constructor of Book class

```
public Book(int id, string name)
{
    id = this.id; // reverse this assignment, and the next line as well
    name = this.name;
}
```

replace with this

```
public Book(int id, string name)
{
    this.id = id; // this is the correct way
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem.
Make sure the context you are using in your controller is referring to the correct connection string.

Example:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnStr", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FileUpload.Models.FileTypesView> FileTypesViews { get; set; }
}

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnStr" connectionString="data source=xxx;initial catalog=&quot;xxx&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```